# LunaCryptokiException: function 'CrystokiConnect failed' returns 0x0 as non root user

Tags: keystore, hsm

I have used Luna SA with SDK for generating keypairs.

When am trying to list the keystore (as non root user) its throwing below exception. If I try as root user, it does list and works fine.

I have given read write permission to non root user.

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: LUNA not found
java.security.KeyStoreException: LUNA not found

Caused by: com.safenetinc.luna.LunaCryptokiException: function 'CrystokiConnect failed' returns 0x0
        at com.safenetinc.luna.LunaCryptokiException.ThrowNew(LunaCryptokiException.java:)
        at com.safenetinc.luna.LunaAPI.Initialize(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Any help, how can I list key stores as a non root user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parent folder, where certificates resides to connect hsm for handshake and luna bin folder should have read and execute permission for non root users who are using the client.

Which I missed!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it got resolved once we provided proper permission to /usr/safenet/lunaclient/

```
chmod -R 777  /usr/safenet/lunaclient/
```

Comment: providing 777 is non suggested and not good practice.. read permission for specific user should resolve your issue..

Comment: If my question helped you to resolve your issue, do upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

From their [official guide](https://thalesdocs.com/gphsm/luna/7.4/docs/pci/Content/install/software/linux_install.htm):

> To allow non-root users or applications access your attached HSMs and partitions, assign the users to the **hsmusers** group. The users you assign to the hsmusers group must exist on the client workstation. Users you add to the hsmusers group are able to access your attached HSMs and partitions. Users who are not part of the hsmusers group are not able to access your attached HSMs and partitions.

`sudo gpasswd --add <username> hsmusers`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I also had to fix the permissions of the file /etc/Chrystoki.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even after providing proper permission to /usr/safenet/lunaclient/. Got it resolved after giving 755 permission to /usr/safenet/ folder

```
chmod -R 755  /usr/safenet/
```